# 3D volume indexing to get arbitrary vectors matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have a 3D volume and a list of `x,y` coordinates. I need to extract from the volume all vectors

```
V(x,y,:)
```

turned `x,y` to linear index but I cannot use:

```
V(ind,:)
```

because Matlab assumes that `ind` is a subscript and I get an error (index exceeded...).
It's OK to use `V(:,ind)` but that's not what I need.

Any way of doing this without `repmat` on the 3rd dimension and use linear index on all three dimensions? I want to avoid this, because the volume is very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/permute.html) to rearrange your data matrix

```
 V2 = permute(V, [3 1 2]);
```

Then you can access the (former) z-data by `V2(:,ind)`, i.e., `V(x,y,:)` would give the same result as `V2(:,ind)`.